# Capybara & RSPEC: ActionController::UnknownFormat: Error. How do i fix this error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

This is the error when i run the capybara test:

```
 Failure/Error:
       respond_to do |format|
         #format.html
         format.js
       end

     ActionController::UnknownFormat:
       ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

This is from the controller file:  (uncommenting format.html didn't work)

```
  def new
    @location = @provider.locations.new
    @address = @location.build_address
    @addresses = []
    respond_to do |format|
      #format.html
      format.js
    end
```

This is the capybara code

```
describe "this tab" do
    it "shows data" do 
      visit locations_profile_path(@provider)
      expect(current_path).to eq("/profile/#{@provider.id}/locations")
      expect(page).to have_content("All Practice Locations")
      expect(page).to have_content('Add New Location')
      Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 20
      click_on 'Add New Location'
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You state that uncommenting `format.html` didn't work, but I'm betting it failed with a different error message, because you don't have an html view. I'm also assuming that the error message you're seeing is coming from the `click_on 'Add New Location'` line which appears to the only part of your test that would call a `new` action. Without seeing the code in your page triggered  by clicking on 'Add New Location' I can't be 100% sure what the issue is, but based on the error I'm guessing that you're not actually using the capybara-webkit driver (even though the question is tagged with that). Really you shouldn't be using the capybara-webkit driver nowadays anyway since it was obsolete years ago.  Rather you should be looking at one of the up-to-date maintained drivers like Selenium, etc. Depending on which version of Rails you're using and what type of tests you're writing you'll want to either look at Rails/RSpecs `driven_by` (for Rails 6+ and system specs) or Capybaras `default_driver` and `javascript_driver` settings if writing feature specs - click_on 'Add New Location'.  If you're not correctly selecting the driver to be used then it would default to the rack-test driver which doesn't support JS and therefore would never make a request for a JS format response.

Other comments on your test

1. You should never be using RSpecs general matchers (eq, etc) with Capybara related info
2. You should not be setting Capybara global settings (default_max_wait_time) inside your test. Instead set the per command options for max wait time, or use `using_wait_time` if needed for multiple commands.
3. There's no point checking for content that you then attempt to click, since the click_on is also checking for its existence

taking those into account your test should be written more like

```
visit locations_profile_path(@provider)
expect(page).to have_current_path("/profile/#{@provider.id}/locations")
expect(page).to have_content("All Practice Locations")
click_on 'Add New Location', wait: 20
```